# How can I do a C# workaround for a specific sql query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am building a hierarchical treelist in C#, I am using sql queries to get my results. However, I cant seem to get this one query to work. It give me exactly what I need in sql-server, but it won't work in C#. Is there a possible workaround for this query?
HTML

```
<div class="Demo">
    <h1>Tree Demo</h1>
    <div class="tree well">
        <ul>
            <li><span>ServerName</span>
            <ul>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rpDatabasesParent" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="loadTables">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li><span><%# Eval("Name") %></span>
                            <ul>
                                <h3>Tables</h3>
                                <asp:Repeater ID="rpTablesChild" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="loadTables">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <li><span><%# Eval("Tables") %></span></li>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The query in question is the second query in my code. It is dynamic and it gives me exactly what I need, but I can't get it to work. I need a workaround , if there is one, to get this query working

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    testConnection();
}

public void testConnection()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(masterConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name From Sys.Databases", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            rpDatabasesParent.DataSource = rdr;
            rpDatabasesParent.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            //log something
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

}

protected void loadTables(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
    Repeater rpTablesChild = (Repeater)item.FindControl("rpTablesChild");

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(masterConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DECLARE @SERVERNAME SYSNAME = @@SERVERNAME, @DB SYSNAME, @Object SYSNAME, @Str NVARCHAR(4000); DECLARE DBList CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT name FROM sys.databases; OPEN DBList; FETCH NEXT FROM DBList INTO @DB; WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN SELECT @Str = 'SELECT name AS Tables FROM '+@DB+'.sys.tables; SELECT TABLE_NAME AS Views FROM '+@DB+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS; SELECT ROUTINE_NAME AS StoredProcedures FROM '+@DB+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES;' EXEC sp_executesql @Str FETCH NEXT FROM DBList INTO @DB; END CLOSE DBList; DEALLOCATE DBList;", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            rpTablesChild.DataSource = rdr;
            rpTablesChild.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            //log something
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the query works, but not when you run it from C#? Are you gettig and error or incorrect data Have you tried running it from a stored procedure?

Comment: Just a hint, put your "query" in stored procedure then run stored procedure from c# code

Comment: I just get blank results , but I will try using a stored procedure, thank you

Comment: Why are you building your querys manually? Have you about using a framework like the enity framework?

Comment: if indeed your code is like that, you're catching errors without doing something. Could be you're getting an error and not even noticing it.

Answer (score 0):

Aside of fact that I would encourage you to look into turning this piece of code into stored procedure it looks like there are missing space characters in few places.

f.ex:

```
@StrFETCH
```

should be

```
@Str FETCH
```

So the whole fixed string is going to be:

```
DECLARE @SERVERNAME SYSNAME= @@SERVERNAME, @DB SYSNAME, @Object SYSNAME, @Str NVARCHAR(4000); DECLARE DBList CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT name FROM sys.databases; OPEN DBList; FETCH NEXT FROM DBList INTO @DB; WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN SELECT @Str = 'SELECT name AS Tables FROM '+@DB+'.sys.tables; SELECT TABLE_NAME AS Views FROM '+@DB+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS; SELECT ROUTINE_NAME AS StoredProcedures FROM '+@DB+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES;' EXEC sp_executesql @Str FETCH NEXT FROM DBList INTO @DB; END CLOSE DBList; DEALLOCATE DBList;
```

Also you need to take into account that this query is going to return multiple resultsets so I am not sure if using DataRead will help you get results.

You could combine all rows into 1 result like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetDbsObjects AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #output (
      [Db] SYSNAME,
      [Type] VARCHAR(20),
      [Name] SYSNAME
    )

    DECLARE @SERVERNAME SYSNAME= @@SERVERNAME, @DB SYSNAME, @Object SYSNAME, @Str NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE DBList CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
    FOR SELECT name
        FROM sys.databases;
    OPEN DBList;
    FETCH NEXT FROM DBList INTO @DB;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @Str = 'INSERT INTO #output([Db], [Type], [Name]) SELECT '''+@DB+''', ''table'', name FROM '+@DB+'.sys.tables;'
            EXEC sp_executesql @Str

            SELECT @Str = 'INSERT INTO #output([Db], [Type], [Name]) SELECT '''+@DB+''', ''view'', TABLE_NAME FROM '+@DB+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS;'
            EXEC sp_executesql @Str

             SELECT @Str = 'INSERT INTO #output([Db], [Type], [Name]) SELECT '''+@DB+''', ''stored procedure'', ROUTINE_NAME FROM '+@DB+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES;'
            EXEC sp_executesql @Str

            FETCH NEXT FROM DBList INTO @DB;
        END
    CLOSE DBList;
    DEALLOCATE DBList;

    SELECT * FROM #output

    DROP TABLE #output
END
```

And then you should be able to run it from c#

```
    ...
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetDbsObjects", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    rpTablesChild.DataSource = rdr;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I believe you have some errors in your query your BEGINSELECT should be BEGIN SELECT and you don't close with END after the BEGIN of the WHILE.

If this doesn't solve your problem, maybe you can try this workaround:

Create a store procedure in SQL server management with input parameters.
Then, you can just execute that procedure in your C# code with the parameters.

Here is an example:

```
  public DataSet RelaEspec(DateTime dtInicio, DateTime dtFim, string CodNo)
    {
        string sql = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            sql = "exec store_procedure @dtInicio, @dtFim, @CodNo ";

            SqlParameterCollection pCol = new SqlParameterCollection();

            pCol.Add("@dtInicio", SqlDbType.DateTime, dtInicio);
            pCol.Add("@dtFim", SqlDbType.DateTime, dtFim);
            pCol.Add("@CodNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1, CodNo);

            return ExecuteDataSet(sql, pCol, SessionID, connectionTimeout);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logErro(ex, "DataSet RelatorioEspecializacao");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Create the stored procedure:

```
USE [YOUR DATABASE]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[store_procedure]
        @SERVERNAME SYSNAME = @@SERVERNAME
      , @DB SYSNAME
      , @Object SYSNAME
      , @Str NVARCHAR(4000);
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE 
DBList CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARDFOR 
SELECT name FROM sys.databases; 
OPEN DBList; 
 FETCH NEXT FROM DBList INTO @DB;
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
 BEGIN 
   SELECT @Str = 'SELECT name AS Tables FROM '+@DB+'.sys.tables; SELECT 
TABLE_NAME AS Views FROM '+@DB+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS; SELECT 
ROUTINE_NAME AS StoredProcedures FROM '+@DB+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES;' 
    EXEC sp_executesql @StrFETCH NEXT FROM DBList INTO @DB; ENDCLOSE DBList; 
 END
    DEALLOCATE DBList

return 

END
GO
```